# How work Phpmyadmin for php 5.6 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: server, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with the installation of phpMyAdmin in my server Ubuntu 20.04.

My version of php is 5.6 but when I install phpMyAdmin and open url /phpmyadmin in my browser, I get the error `HTTP ERROR 500`

My version of mysql is 5.6

I opened the error log of apache2 and inside have this error.

```
PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Loader.php on line 23

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Loader.php on line 116
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to *not* use a tool like phpMyAdmin and instead use an external MySQL client that connects via SSH like TablePlus, Beehive, or the like. The PHP errors you have are because the version of phpMyAdmin that you're installing is written for PHP 5.x, which has a lot of incompatibilities with PHP 7.x, which shipped with Ubuntu 20.04. Unless you are comfortable with PHP development, choosing a better tool is the simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PHP 5 version installed you can use phpMyAdmin 4.9 by installing it manually from the phpMyAdmin website.
Else use phpMyAdmin 5.1 that supports from PHP 7.1 to 8.1.

But maybe you can check one of the Debian/Ubuntu ways to install a mostly up to date phpMyAdmin. Seems like you installed a Debian/Ubuntu version because of your path "/usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Loader.php".

See: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu

Hope it helps you,
William from the phpMyAdmin team